# Create elements in JQuery inside other

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know how to create a element whit JQuery, but I don't know how to place that element, exactly where I want.

```
<form action="/register" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <span class="help-block">Username</span>
  <input id="checkuser" type="text" name="nuser" placeholder="Username"/>
  <span class="help-block">Email</span>
  <input id="mail" type="text" name="nmail" placeholder="Your m@il"/>
  <span class="help-block">Password</span>
  <input type="password" name="npass" placeholder="Your password"/>
  <span class="help-block">Avatar</span>
  <input type="file" name="navatar" accept="image/*">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm doing AJAX request with JQuery, so, depends of the result of the request, I create, or not an element to the left of the inputs. How I do that?

Thank's advance!

Comment: "*...the left of the inputs...*," can you rephrase that?

Comment: look at `Manipulation` section of API. Contains numerous insertion methods you can use  http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/. They all provide examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *left* of an input you mean before it then you can use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

```
$("<span/>", {
  text: "My newly created span element"
}).insertBefore("input#checkuser");
```

Or, also you may use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).